# Pushed a commit to master branch that has most of the files at an older state, and directories were re-structured in this commit

Tags: git, github

I'm having troubling figuring out the git workflow needed to fix this.

Master branch was a good number of commits ahead from re-structured branch.

Restructure branch re-structured a lot of directories. It was pushed to master and overwrote a lot of the work that has been done. This includes files being overwritten to an earlier state, and several files deleted.

I tried branching off master to a fix-master branch, reverting master hard, and then merging master onto the fix-master branch. This just made the fix-master branch the same as the initial state I was trying to fix - I expected it to throw up merge errors and allow me to fix them but it didn't.

What workflow would be best to fix this issue?

Comment: It seems like merging `restructure` into `master` produced a bad merge. You may want to look into [undoing merges](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html).